# How to ensure that uploaded file is video or picture?

Tags: media

I want to be sure that user uploaded files are *real* videos or pictures, but not just a piece of text renamed to textfile.jpg. What are the ways to ensure?

I see the only way: detect type of file by it's extension and then, depending on file type, try to get information about it (by Imagemagick or ffmpeg).

Is there any other ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many UNIX-like systems, you have the `file` program that inspects the file contents. On my Ubuntu system, this accepts the `--mime-type` flag (Googling for `file` is a nightmare, so I won't try to look up how standardized this is):

```
$ file --mime-type some_image.jpg
some_image.jpg: image/jpeg
```

You can easily parse the output to see if the MIME type starts with `image/` or `video/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command, which would tell you the file type, provided you are on a host that allows you to use functions like PHP's [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

Answer (score 0):

If mdm's answer doesn't apply in your case, then you could check out www.wotsit.org - it provides details on a huge array of file formats...

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the ability to identify files by the file signature (also called "magic numbers").

The [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command provides this, however, you can also implement this yourself, using publicly available lists of magic numbers:

[FILE SIGNATURES TABLE](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the Fileinfo extension built-in as of 5.3, and available via PECL for earlier versions.  It will tell you the MIME type of the file, among other things: http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php